# Need help removing extra TOC text from number lists used as TOC levels

Tags: table-of-contents

It's been over 20 years since I've used MS Word, but I've been pressed into duty writing a document for a family member.  There are a few things I've forgotten how to do.  I'm a bit stuck and I'm requesting some help.

I'm trying to build a TOC in MS Word, but I'm having problems restricting my TOC to only keywords; it instead includes the text in the body of my document.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
ARTICLE 1 - DEFINITIONS  
   1.1 Alpha. "Alpha" shall mean blah blah blah. 
   1.2 Bravo. “Bravo” shall mean blah blah blah. 
   1.3 Charlie. "Charlie" shall mean blah blah blah.
```

I want this:

```
ARTICLE 1 - DEFINITIONS............................... Page 1
   1.1 Alpha.......................................... Page 1 
   1.2 Bravo.......................................... Page 1
   1.3 Charlie........................................ Page 1
```

But I end up with this:

```
ARTICLE 1 - DEFINITIONS............................... Page 1
   1.1 Alpha. "Alpha" shall mean blah blah blah....... Page 1
   1.2 Bravo. “Bravo” shall mean blah blah blah....... Page 1
   1.3 Charlie. "Charlie" shall mean blah blah blah... Page 1
```

I don't want the verbiage listed behind each keyword (Alpha, Bravo, Charlie) appearing in the TOC.

Hopefully, there's a simple way of doing this.  I've looked through the web and could not find a solution, probably because I couldn't adequately describe my issue in a search box.

Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.